# Java mouselistener rectangle issue

Tags: java

I have a programme where there are sticky notes. You click on them to pick them up and click again to place them somewhere. My problem is when there are two or more sticky notes on top of each other they both get picked up I only want the top one to be picked up. How can I fix this here is my code so far:

```
  public class PhoneMsg {

public int x, y, id, hour, minute;
public boolean drag = false;
public String name, lastname, msg, msg2, msg3;

public Rectangle rx = new Rectangle(x + 290, y, 20, 20);
public Rectangle rdrag = new Rectangle(x, y, 310, 20);

public boolean remove;

private Image img;

public PhoneMsg(int x, int y, String name, String lastname, int hour, int minute, int id) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.id = id;

    rdrag = new Rectangle(x, y, 310, 20);
    rx = new Rectangle(x + 290, y, 20, 20);
    genMsg();
}

public void tick() {
    rx = new Rectangle(x + 290, y, 20, 20);
    rdrag = new Rectangle(x, y, 310, 20);

    if (rx.intersects(Comp.mx, Comp.my, 1, 1)) {
        if (Comp.ml) {
            remove = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < play.ph.pp.toArray().length; i++) {
                // play.ph.pp.get(i).canreadtxt = true;
            }

        }
    }

    // dragging
    if (drag) {
        x = Comp.mx - 140;
        y = Comp.my - 10;
    }

    if (msg == null) {
        genMsg();
    }
}

    public void render(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_GASP);
    g2.setRenderingHints(rh);

    // display
    g.setColor(new Color(19, 165, 34));
    g.fillRect(x, y, 310, 150);
    g.setColor(new Color(27, 53, 16));
    g.drawRect(x, y, 310, 150);
    g.setColor(new Color(27, 53, 16));
    g.drawRect(x, y, 310, 20);

    // Exit part
    g.setColor(new Color(27, 53, 16));
    g.drawRect(rx.x, rx.y, rx.width, rx.height);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.BOLD, 12));
    g.drawString("X", rx.x + 7, rx.y + 15);

    // name
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.BOLD, 12));
    g.drawString("" + name + " " + lastname + "'s Recent Messages", x + 5, y + 15);

    // details
    String msg11 = String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
    String msg21 = String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
    String msg31 = String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);

    if(play.hud.wifi >= 1){
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.BOLD, 12));
    g.drawString("  " + msg, x + 2, y + 38);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.BOLD, 12));
    g.drawString("  " + msg2, x + 2, y + 58);

    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.BOLD, 12));
    g.drawString("  " + msg3, x + 2, y + 78);
    }else if(play.hud.wifi <= 0){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        g.drawString("Lost Connection", x +90, y +85);
        
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("italic", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        g.drawString("_________________", x +70, y +88);
        
    }

}
```

}
and this is the part in the mouse listener that lets u pick up the sticky notes:

```
     // dragging msg's
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < play.ph.pm.toArray().length; i1++) {
            if (play.ph.pm.get(i1).drag == false && play.holding == false) {
                if (play.ph.pm.get(i1).rdrag.contains(Comp.mx, Comp.my)) {
                    play.ph.pm.get(i1).drag = true;
                    play.holding = true;

                }
            } else {
                play.ph.pm.get(i1).drag = false;
                play.holding = false;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of (play.ph.pm.get(i1).drag == false && play.holding == false) you can do (!play.ph.pm.get(i1).drag && !play.holding) where ! means NOT.

Comment: ye I know but sometimes I just do it this way for no reason at all

Answer (score 0):

If you break out of the for loop you can pick up the first sticky note the code gets to when they're overlapping.

```
if (play.ph.pm.get(i1).rdrag.contains(Comp.mx, Comp.my)) {
    play.ph.pm.get(i1).drag = true;
    play.holding = true;
    break; // Found sticky note, exits loop
}
```

Or if this conflicts with your else statement, simply create a flag.

```
 // dragging msg's
 boolean gotCard = false;
 for (int i1 = 0; i1 < play.ph.pm.toArray().length; i1++) {
     if (play.ph.pm.get(i1).drag == false && play.holding == false && gotNote == false) { // Added gotNote check
         if (play.ph.pm.get(i1).rdrag.contains(Comp.mx, Comp.my)) {
             play.ph.pm.get(i1).drag = true;
             play.holding = true;
             gotNote = true; // Set flag to true
         }
     } else {
         play.ph.pm.get(i1).drag = false;
         play.holding = false;
     }
 }
```

However you should probably have a z-index implemented to be able to tell which sticky note is on top then sort your array by that z-index.

Comment: what is a z index and how can I implement it

Comment: A z-index is what layer something is on. In simple cases 0 is the bottom, and 1 is on top of 0, 2 is on top of 1, etc. So it makes it easy to check which object is on top of another. You can set this by checking if two notes overlap when you put one on top of another, and set the z-index of the top one to the underneath objects z-index + 1.

Comment: ok thanks but I have the iq of an elephant could you explain how I might do this if it not to much hastle if it is to much hastle don't worry but it

Comment: You should probably create a new question for that, unless I didn't answer your current question.